# Cannot return reference to local variable

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I have a trait:

```
pub trait HasQuux {
    fn quux(&self) -> &Quux;
}
```

Most structs which implement this have a `Quux` field, possibly nested, to which they can return a reference.  e.g.

```
pub struct Foo {
    ...
    q: Quux,
    ...
}

impl HasQuux for Foo {
    fn quux(&self) -> &Quux {
        &self.q
    }
}
```

How can I implement `HasQuux` for structs which must calculate their Quux?

This implementation:

```
impl HasQuux for Bar {
    fn quux(&self) -> &Quux {
        let q: Quux = self.calc_quux();
        &q
    }
}
```

causes:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to local variable `q`
  --> /home/fadedbee/test.rs:38:3
   |
38 |         &q
   |         ^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

I am keen for `quux()` to return a reference, as 99% of structs implementing `HasQuux` have a `Quux` field.

I understand why this isn't possible.

Can I create a temporary `Quux` whose lifetime matches the lifetime of `Bar` and return a reference to that?

Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I create a temporary `Quux` whose lifetime matches the lifetime of Bar and return a reference to that?

The short answer is: you can't. What you can do is have `quux` return a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) (copy-on-write, not the bovine):

```
fn quux(&self) -> Cow<'_, Quux>
```

The 99% of impls that have a `self.q` will return `Cow::Borrowed(&self.q)`, and the 1% that don't will return `Cow::Owned(self.calc_quux())`. ([Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7085aa182e49a3153009a34a1989f91))

If you can't change the trait definition, then it is very unlikely that you will manage to return a reference in safe Rust (without [leaking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) `Quux`). First, you'd need to store the calculated `q` in an `Option<Quux>` inside `self`, which is probably not what you want. But even if it were, you'd have the issue of `HasQuux::quux` taking `&self` and not `&mut self`. Using `RefCell<Option<Quux>>` would allow you to store the calculated `Quux`, but not to return a reference to it because Rust can't prevent you from overwriting the `RefCell` contents elsewhere in the code.

If it is acceptable to cache the `&Quux` given out, you can implement a helper type<sup>1</sup> to encapsulate interior mutability:

```
mod lazy {
    use std::cell::RefCell;

    #[derive(Debug, Default)]
    pub struct Lazy<T> {
        content: RefCell<Option<T>>,
    }

    impl<T> Lazy<T> {
        pub fn ensure(&self, make_content: impl FnOnce() -> T) -> &T {
            if self.content.borrow().is_none() {
                *self.content.borrow_mut() = Some(make_content());
            }
            // safety: self.content.borrow_mut() must never be called again
            // because we give out a shared reference to the content
            let content = unsafe { &*self.content.as_ptr() };
            // unwrap: we've ensured above that the option is Some
            content.as_ref().unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

The above type uses unsafe in its implementation, but provides a fully safe interface (as far as I can tell - one can never be 100% sure with unsafe code). Another `borrow_mut()` mentioned in the safety comment cannot be executed by outside code because the fields of `Lazy` are private. Still, if the definition of `Lazy` were modified incorrectly, the compiler couldn't catch the error because we used `unsafe` to convince it that we know what we're doing.

With this helper type, we can provide a simple and safe implementation of `HasQuux` for `Bar`:

```
struct Bar {
    cached_q: lazy::Lazy<Quux>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn calc_quux(&self) -> Quux {
        Quux
    }
}

impl HasQuux for Bar {
    fn quux(&self) -> &Quux {
        self.cached_q.ensure(|| self.calc_quux())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=929f55a303bf3d27862eac2edd1986ba)

---

<sup>1</sup>

Or just use the [`OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.7.2/once_cell/unsync/struct.OnceCell.html) type from the `once_cell` crate whose [`get_or_init`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.7.2/once_cell/unsync/struct.OnceCell.html#method.get_or_init) method is exactly equivalent to `Lazy::ensure()` defined above.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very comprehensive answer.  I've had to rethink my structures as using Cow created too much noise in the rest of the source.